# how to install modules to python 2.7 on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I tried to install these two modules

```
pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16
pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16
```

Before install, I switched from python 3 to python 2.7 in the VS code. because I want to install these two modules to python 2.7 and run with python 2.7.

I check `pip freeze`, But 2 modules is not there.

I check pip version, output looks like this

```
pip --version
pip 19.2.2 from /Users/donperera/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

How to install these 2 modules on to python 2.7 and run the project with python 2.7?

Comment: Why? Python 2.7 is EOL since Jan 2020

Comment: @DeepSpace They could be developing for a legacy program that's in 2.7

Comment: Use full path for *pip*. Or use `${FULL_PATH_TO_PYTHON27} -m pip install ...`.

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments? I'll second what @DeepSpace asked, why use Python 2?

Answer (score 0):

Vscode doesn't effect pip because it is a command line app.

First like the comment says, type `python2 -m ensurepip`
If this doesn't work see https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ensurepip.html

Then
This is because the default python on your machine is 3.7.
Try typing in the terminal `python2 -m pip install <module or package >`

Comment: Try `python2 -m ensurepip` first if that doesn't work, see https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ensurepip.html.